# Load HTML Table from XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am loading my table on document.ready() from a json file as follows

document load....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        getSummaryData(function (data1) {
            var dataarray=new Array();
            dataarray.push(data1);


            $('#summaryTable').DataTable({
                data: dataarray,
                "columns": [
               ---
               ---
```

and retrieving the data from a file as follows

```
    function getSummaryData(cb_func1) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data/summary.json",
        success: cb_func1
    });
    console.log(cb_func1)
}
```

This was essentially loading dummy data so i could I could figure out how to load the table correctly etc. This works fine.

It does following
1. page loads
2. reads data from file
3. populates table

In reality, the data will not be loaded from file but will be returned from xhr response but I am unable to figure out 
how to wire it all together. The use case is

1. POST a file via XMLHttpRequest
2. Get response
3. populate table (same data format as file)

I will post the file as follows...

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('select');
    var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload');

    ---
    form.onsubmit = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    ---
---
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 // Open the connection.  
 xhr.open('POST', 'localhost/uploader', true);      

  // handler on response
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {

            console.log("resp: "+xhr);
            console.log("resptxt: "+xhr.responseText);

            //somehow load table with xhr.responseText

        } else {
            alert('ooops');
        }
    };

    // Send the Data.
    xhr.send(formData);
```

So ideally I need one empty row in the table or similar until someone uploads a file and then the table gets populated with the response.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('POST', "youruploadserver.com/whatever", true);
xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        dostuff = this.responseText;
  };//end onreadystate
 xhr1.send();
```

It looks mostly correct, You want the `this.readyState == 4` in there. what is your question, how to populate a table from the response?
That also depends on how you are going to send the data and how the server is going to parse the data, looks like you want to use a json format which is smart. `JSON.stringify(formdata)` before you send it and then make sure your server parses it as a json object Using body-parser depending on what server you are using. and then you `JSON.stringify()` the object to send it back.